# Second AJAX based on result of first one

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following JavaScript/jQuery code that sometime works and sometime not.

```
//First AJAX
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/API/User/GetCode/'+  $("#email").val(),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).done(function (data) {
        code = data;
    }).fail(function () {
        code = "";
    });

//Second AJAX
    var data = {
        Email: $("#email").val(),
        Password: $("#password").val(),
        ConfirmPassword: $("#confirmPassword").val(),
        Code: code,
        Type: "External"
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/API/Account/Register',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).done(function (data) {
        var result = "Success";
        var message = "Verify your email address to confirm your account.";
        resultPage(result, message);
    }).fail(showError);
```

In the first AJAX I get a code and based on this code I call the second AJAX.

As I don't want to set `async=false` when the first AJAX is being called first it works fine (the first AJAX returns the `code` and then the second AJAX is being called properly with the `code` parameter), otherwise it doesn't work.

I think that I have to add a promise but I'm not sure how to do it in such a case.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Move your second ajax inside `.done` of the first one

Comment: Wxactly what @SandeepNayak says. The JavaScript code continues before the ajax call is completed. When it is completed the done callback is called

Comment: Thank you both for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getCode() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/API/User/GetCode/'+  $("#email").val(),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).done(function (data) {
        sendData(data)
    }).fail(function () {
        code = "";
    });
}  

function sendData(code) {
var data = {
        Email: $("#email").val(),
        Password: $("#password").val(),
        ConfirmPassword: $("#confirmPassword").val(),
        Code: code,
        Type: "External"
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/API/Account/Register',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).done(function (data) {
        var result = "Success";
        var message = "Verify your email address to confirm your account.";
        resultPage(result, message);
    }).fail(showError);

}
getCode()
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the second ajax request inside some function and call that function when first ajax request is completed.

```
function FirstAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/API/User/GetCode/'+  $("#email").val(),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).done(function (data) {
        SecondAjax(data)
    }).fail(function () {
        code = "";
    });
}  

function SecondAjax(code) {
var data = {
        Email: $("#email").val(),
        Password: $("#password").val(),
        ConfirmPassword: $("#confirmPassword").val(),
        Code: code,
        Type: "External"
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/API/Account/Register',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).done(function (data) {
        var result = "Success";
        var message = "Verify your email address to confirm your account.";
        resultPage(result, message);
    }).fail(showError);

}
FirstAjax();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

> Put the second ajax inside the ajax done method

```
//First AJAX
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/API/User/GetCode/'+  $("#email").val(),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(data)
}).done(function (data) {
    code = data;
     //Second AJAX
      var nextData = {
         Email: $("#email").val(),
         Password: $("#password").val(),
         ConfirmPassword: $("#confirmPassword").val(),
         Code: code,
         Type: "External"
      };

    $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/API/Account/Register',
          contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          data: JSON.stringify(nextData)
    }).done(function (data) {
      var result = "Success";
      var message = "Verify your email address to confirm your account.";
      resultPage(result, message);
    }).fail(showError);
}).fail(function () {
    code = "";
});
```